# Unity3D, C#. Input does not work on iOS Simulator

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm new to IOS and just tried to make the simplest game just for test it on IOS Simulator.
Here is the all code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour {

private Rigidbody2D rb;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rb = transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) || Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
}
```

As you see, when user press the button or just touch the screen, some object fly up.

Of course in Unity it works fine, but when I make IOS build (with IOS Simulator SDK) and try to run it in XCODE it runs, but when I press a mouse button - controlled object does not fly up.

[Here is the video of all that process.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wpg_qNXrSA)

What could be the problem? Why it doesn't work?

Comment: In my experience, Unity behaves very strangely in simulators, to the point that they're essentially useless for testing. Can you reproduce the problem on a real build?

Comment: no, i can't, but now all right